# Query Azure SQL DB (VM) in LUIS Bot

Tags: c#, sql, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a BotFramework Project I built through azure with an integrated LUIS API for Language Processing, within my BasicLuisDialog.cs file I want to add a call to action for one of the LuisIntents to be a SQL DB Query, which takes the text the user entered into the bot, query that name against the SQL DB, then return the details about that person.

I've currently added this in the BasicLuisDialog.cs under the intent I want it to query from:

```
 [LuisIntent("Who_is_Employee")]
    public async Task Who_is_EmployeeIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        EntityRecommendation recommendation;
        if(result.TryFindEntity("employee_name", out recommendation))
        {
            string role = EmployeeService.FindEmployee(recommendation.Entity);
            await context.PostAsync(" " + role);
        }
```

I created an EmployeeService.cs

```
using LuisBot.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LuisBot.Service
{
    public class EmployeeService
    {
        public static string FindEmployee(string name)
        {
            string title = null;
            using(EmployeeDb db = new EmployeeDb())
            {
               var rec = db.vw_Everyone.Where(c => c.givenName ==     name).FirstOrDefault();
            title = rec.title;

        }

        return title;
    }
}
```

}

I created an EmployeeDb.cs:

```
namespace LuisBot.Model
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class EmployeeDb : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeDb()
        : base("name=EmployeeDb")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<vw_Everyone> vw_Everyone { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
}
```

And the SQL View, called vw.Everyone.cs:

```
namespace LuisBot.Model
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class vw_Everyone
{
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string mail { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string SN { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string givenName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string mobile { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string telephoneNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string department { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string sectors { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string region { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string physicalDeliveryOfficeName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string company { get; set; }

    public int? userAccountControl { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string sAMAccountName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string ADsPath { get; set; }

    [StringLength(513)]
    public string CN { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4)]
    public string ipPhone { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(Sorry if my code is a bit unformatted, I'm new to programming and StackFlow)

This code I thought would work, but doesn't query the SQL DB and return me the info I want, I must be doing something wrong just can't figure out what.

Comment: Hey Mark - what have you tried so far? Your question might get closed in its current form for being too broad. Generally, if a question has a statement like "What's the best to do $task?", it's probably too broad. Generally questions on stackoverflow should provide some code to work from. Even posting your `LuisIntent` in `BasicLuisDialog.cs` would be a good starting point.

Comment: Hey Michael, let me update it with some code - thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: I've updated it with some additional code, hope this helps give an insight into what's I've got so far

Comment: Much better! I'll take a look and see if I can help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when you remove the `Where()` clause in your `FindEmployee()` method? Does it return any data at all? If so, my guess would be an issue with the string comparison.

Comment: It just returned the context PostAsync for that Intent, nothing else returned

Answer (score 1):

@Mark Hawkins-Wood It looks like in your  `BasicLuisDialog.cs` you only do something if your `LuisResult` contains an `employee_name` entity. **Are you certain that your results actually contains such entity?**

You can check by including an else statement to take some action if there is no `employee_name` entity in your Luis results:

```cs
EntityRecommendation recommendation;
        if (result.TryFindEntity("employee_name", out recommendation))
        {
            string role = EmployeeService.FindEmployee(recommendation.Entity);
            await context.PostAsync(" " + role);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("no employee_name");
        }
```

Comment: They do contain entities known as Communication.ContactName (a prebuilt domain entity within LUIS).

Comment: I have now managed to get this working, I don't particularly remember exactly what fixed it as I've made significant changes to the coding but it's working now.